# FB.login with incorrect redirect_uri

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using flash GrahpAPI_web sdk which is a as3 flash extension the communicate with the Javascript SDK.

Regardless, I'm trying to get the oauth dialog to show up as a popup, as popup's. 
When I run the FB.init followed by FB.login call's, the resulting oauth URL includes a redirect that I didn't not specify, nor can I see clearly how to specify it.

Here's a friend view of the oauth URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
api_key=<APP_ID>
app_id=<APP_ID>
client_id=<APP_ID>
display=popup
domain=app.local.MYAPP.com
locale=en_US&origin=1
redirect_uri=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=8#cb=f35f1a383cdde0a
origin=http%3A%2F%=app.local.MYAPP.com%2Ff38af6b0241d006
domain==app.local.MYAPP.com
relation=opener
frame=fc22754c0e4d
response_type=token,signed_request 
scope=read_stream, publish_stream 
sdk=joey
```

The problem is the redirect_uri which I didn't specify.
If I replace with app.local.MYAPP.com, it appears to work correctly.

How can I get FB.login to implement the correct redirect_uri?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: I've got this same problem with the JS SDK. `FB.Login` doesn't seem to expect a `redirect_uri`!

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble a similar, so I did it a little differently. Maybe something like this will work for you. I used this javascript:

```
window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=<APP_ID>
    &redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URL>
    &response_type=token
    &scope=publish_stream");
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add the exact sub domain in valid oauth redirect uri in this page!
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appid}/fb-login/